# Remove css applied to element of particular type

Tags: jquery, css, overriding

My css file has a class defined for all anchors as below and I cannot modify it.

```
.div a{
    color: red;
}
```

Because of this, all anchors on my page gets this color. I need to supress this for some (say 10 out of 20) anchors on page, preferabally by writing some other class(some js will also be ok). However, I donot want to specify what new color will be. It should inherit from an element (say some other divs having respective css classes specifying different colors) containing that anchor. How can I achieve it?

Comment: can you not add a class to the anchors you do (or don't) want to use this style? Then target them separately

Comment: `.div.someotherclass a {color: inherit;}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is what [`inherit`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/inherit) is for. From the Mozilla Developer Network:

> The `inherit` value is allowed on every CSS property. It causes the element for which it is specified to take the Computed value of the property from its parent element.

So if your anchor should have the same color specified by your parent element, that is the way to go.

<kbd>[**JSBin Demo**](http://jsbin.com/orenic/2/edit)</kbd>

Comment: Will only be applicable when inheriting from the parent element which is does not seem to do in the question.

Comment: Which is actually what is specified in the OP's question: *It should inherit from an element containing that anchor*.

Comment: I'll correct to *might not seem*. If you have elements in between with different color values you cannot achieve this.

Comment: inherit was the key! I was trying to achieve this by using !important and messed up. Didn't thought of inherit. Many Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
div a.specific { color: inherit; }
```

This way you "clear" the color settings at specific level at anchor tags with class="specific".

Answer (score 0):

apply another class to those elements

```
div a.classname { color: inherit; }
```

Comment: `inherit` uses the parent element, so most likely not applicable.

Comment: Which is actually what is specified in the OP's question: *It should inherit from an element containing that anchor*